# Ubuntu on Jetson TK1 fails to boot with external drive

Tags: boot, nvidia, upstart

**The hardware:**  An NVIDIA Jetson TK1, an external Samsung drive hanging off the SATA port, an ethernet connection.

**The two related problems:**

1)  When trying to reboot, if the external drive is plugged in, the boot process hangs during or after:

> starting bridge socket events into upstart

If the external drive is not plugged in, I get an error and a chance to (S)kip or (M)anually recover.  Skipping allows the rest of the boot to proceed successfully.

2)  After (S)kipping and rebooting, if I then plug the drive in, it mounts successfully... and I immediately lose the ethernet connection.

**The question:**  What might I be doing wrong, here, to cause these odd behaviors, and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive was FAT32 formatted, /etc/fstab was trying to mount as EXT4.

Why this caused a networking issue is beyond me, but it did and is now solved.